# Protect file upload for PHP and Slim

Tags: php, file-upload, slim

I have REST API written in PHP and base on Slim Framework.

```
use Slim\Http\UploadedFile;
$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
$uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['myFileName'];
```

How should i protect file uploading script? I want not only to set limits to file size but also protect my web server from uploading anything except images (jpg, png). What are the best practices for file uploading scripts in Slim?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the upload filesize limit in your server's php.ini, simply change the value of the `upload_max_filesize` directive to the maximum limit you want.

As for only allowing certain filetypes, you can achieve this using something like the following:

```
<?php
$extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$allowed = ["image/jpeg", "image/png"];
if(!in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
    $error = "File type is not allowed!";
}
```